# Словить id пользователя который покинул беседу

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```
if event.type == VkEventType.CHAT_UPDATE:
  if event.update_type == VkChatEventType.USER_LEFT:
    #?
```

Не знаю как словить ID страницы человека который покинул беседу. Прощу помощи.

**P.S. Другие решения на форуме не помогают — они просто не работают**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
if event.type == VkEventType.CHAT_UPDATE:
    if event.update_type == VkChatEventType.USER_LEFT: #кик за выход из беседы
        vk.messages.send(random_id = 0, peer_id = event.peer_id, message = "@id" + str(event.info['user_id']) + " покинул беседу. Кикаем его...")
        vk.messages.removeChatUser(chat_id = event.chat_id, user_id = event.info['user_id'])
```

`event.info` вовзращает словарь с `id` пользователя.